# What is the crux of difference between N version programming and self monitoring architecture?

Tags: system-reliability, fault-tolerance

Source-:[https://cs.ccsu.edu/~stan/classes/CS410/Notes16/11-ReliabilityEngineering.html](https://cs.ccsu.edu/%7Estan/classes/CS410/Notes16/11-ReliabilityEngineering.html)

This is self monitoring architecture. So here computations carried across 2 channels, if they both provide same result then system is operating correctly else failure has occurred.
Hardware and software in each module is different to avoid common mode failure.

This is N version programming. Here also software should be written by different person, different algorithm, different programming language etc. So what's the difference, both seem same thing to me
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The difference is in what is done if the outputs are different:

- In the self-monitoring architecture, if the outputs are different then a fault is indicated; no recovery is possible - i.e. this is a fault *detection* architecture.
- In the N-version architecture, the output selector is a voting mechanism which selects the output which is agreed on by the majority - i.e. it allows for both fault detection and limited recovery, The limitation is that it can recover from a failure in strictly less than half the implementations, which is why it should always be used with N odd.